# ArrayOutOfBounds When using addHeaderView() with EndlessAdapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter, commonsware-cwac

I am using `EndlessAdapter` by `Commonsware`.  When I have a `header` view added I get my `listView`, this I get this error and `LogCat`:

```
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3207)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13715)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3653)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12650)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1198)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2173)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-22 17:06:15.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I remove the headerview, I get past this point.

Supplemental: Here is other code in case this is unrelated to header view:

```
public class EndlessProfileAdapter extends EndlessAdapter implements
            IItemsReadyListener {

        private boolean hasMoreData = true;
        private RotateAnimation rotate = null;
        private View pendingView = null;
        private ArrayList<ProfileReview> profileList;

        public EndlessProfileAdapter(Context context,
                ArrayList<ProfileReview> profileList, Typeface tf) {
            super(new ProfileAdapter(context, profileList, tf));

            this.profileList = profileList;

            rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(600);
            rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

        }

@Override
protected boolean cacheInBackground() throws Exception {
    Log.d("Cache Array Size", String.valueOf(profileList.size()));
    new ReviewTask(this, profileList.size()).execute();
    return hasMoreData;
}

@Override
protected void appendCachedData() {

}

void startProgressAnimation() {
    if (pendingView != null) {
        pendingView.startAnimation(rotate);
    }
}

public void onItemsReady(ArrayList<ProfileReview> data) {

    profileList.addAll(data);
    endlessAdapter.onDataReady();
    hasMoreData = profileList.isEmpty();
}
```

Inside Task `onPostExecute()`:

```
profileList = new ArrayList<ProfileReview>();

            for (int i = startPoint; i < startPoint + 10; i++) {
                ProfileReview p = new ProfileReview(itemIdList.get(i),
                        reviewIdList.get(i), reviews.get(i), datelist.get(i),
                        itemslist.get(i), ratings.get(i), cats.get(i));
                profileList.add(p);
            }

            return profileList;
```

The `EndlessAdapter` takes groups of ten in the list.  The first 10 work... but on 11, it crashes.  The LogCat crash actually happens on the second round of 10 (so the 11th item after the user scrolls past the first 10 in the list), and crashes just before  `profileList.add(p);`

**Updated with Requested Information**

inside `onActivityCreated()`:

```
       // for adapter constructor 
       tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
            "fonts/listitemfont.ttf");


   LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.profile_header, listView, false);

    listView = getListView();
    listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

            // stuff like settings up buttons inside header

            // just before end of  `onActivityCreated()`

        if (endlessAdapter == null) {
           if (getActivity() != null) {

            profileList = new ArrayList<ProfileReview>();
            endlessAdapter = new EndlessProfileAdapter(getActivity(),
                    profileList, tf);
            endlessAdapter.setRunInBackground(false);
            listView.setAdapter(endlessAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the code where you are creating the `EndlessAdapter` and setting up the header view.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I have updated question with the info you asked for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EndlessAdapter` is not going to be able to support header or footer views. The `HeaderListViewAdapter` that is created when you use header or footer views makes some assumptions about the underlying adapter that are not always going to be the case with an `EndlessAdapter`.

I have updated the `EndlessAdapter` documentation to point out the limitation.

Comment: Ok, good enough.  Thought I read somewhere there is a solution with `MergeAdapter`?  I guess that was related to something else.

Comment: @KickingLettuce: `MergeAdapter` *might* work with `EndlessAdapter`. And if it doesn't, that's something I am more likely to be able to fix.

Comment: So there is no solution / workaround to put some header view with Endless adapter? I need so much.

Comment: @MicheleVirgilio: I think that `EndlessAdapter` would work with my `MergeAdapter`, with a bit of work. This question was specifically about `addHeaderView()`/`addFooterView()`.